# How to pass data between Fragments in Xamarin?

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to pass data between two fragments. How can I do it?

This code gives me an error:

**Fragment 1:**

```
myips = myip.Text;
mytracks = int.Parse(mytrack.Text);

intent = new Intent(this.Activity, typeof(TabFragment2));

intent.PutExtra("MyData", myip.Text);
intent.PutExtra("MyData1", mytrack.Text);
```

**Fragment 2:**

```
string myips = Activity.Intent.GetStringExtra("MyData");
int mytracks = int.Parse(Activity.Intent.GetStringExtra("MyData1"));
```

Comment: What's the error? It seems like you have a typo on the first Fragment where you say `mytrack` instead of `mytracks` (the last line).

Comment: @hankide  System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String       >>>>int mytracks = int.Parse(Activity.Intent.GetStringExtra("MyData1"));

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/fragments_walkthrough/part_1_-_walkthrough/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> intent = new Intent(this.Activity, typeof(TabFragment2));

A [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) is a piece of an application's user interface or behavior that **can be placed in an Activity**, you shouldn't use this method to open a `Fragment`.

Open your `TabFragment2` like this :

```
var fragment = new TabFragment2();
// Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment with this one inside the frame.
var fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.fragment, fragment );
fragmentTransaction.Commit();
```

For for information, you could read the [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/), here is an [example](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/HoneycombGallery/);

> I want to pass data between two fragments.

When you use `fragmentTransaction.Replace` method to open your `TabFragment2`, you could pass data like this :

When you open `Fragment2` :

```
Fragment2 fragment = new Fragment2();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.PutString("param", myip.Text);
args.PutInt("paramInt", 12);
fragment.Arguments = args;
```

In **Fragment2**, get data from `Arguments` :

```
 public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
      View view = LayoutInflater.From(Activity).Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment2, null);
      if (Arguments != null)
        {
            String mParam1 = Arguments.GetString("param");    
            int mParam2 = Arguments.GetInt("paramInt");
        }
  }
```