# Xamarin Passing EditText from Fragments To Fragments

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I got fragment named Rating.cs this rating.cs is where the searchText is. Now I'm trying to do is to get the searchText.text and pass it to the next fragment where this searchText is a condition in sorting.
Here is my code

> Rating.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using PediburRatingApp;
using PediburRatingApp.Adapter;
using PediburRatingApp.DataModels;
using PediburRatingApp.Fragments;

namespace PediburRatingApp.Activity
{

    public class Rating : Fragment
    {
        Button submit_button;
        public EditText searchText;

        List<Drivers> DriversList;

        View view;
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);


            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.rating, container, false);
            submit_button = (Button)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.submit_rating);
            searchText = (EditText)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.searchText);


            submit_button.Click += SubmitButton_Click;

            return view;
        }


        Fragment fragment;
        private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText.Text))
            {
                Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.Make(view, "Please Enter A Value ", Snackbar.LengthShort);
                snackBar.Show();
            }
            else
            {

                FragmentTransaction transaction = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

                fragment = new DriversListFrag();

                 transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.FramePage, fragment);
                transaction.Commit();

            }


        }



    }
}
```

> DriversListFrag

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using PediburRatingApp;
using PediburRatingApp.Activity;
using PediburRatingApp.Adapter;
using PediburRatingApp.DataModels;
using PediburRatingApp.EventListener;
using PediburRatingApp.Fragments;

namespace PediburRatingApp.Fragments
{

    public class DriversListFrag : Fragment
    {
        View view;
        RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
        List<Drivers> DriversList;
        DriversAdapter adapter;
        DriversListener driversListener;
        EditText Rating.searchText;



        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


        }
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DriversList, container, false);

            myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.myRecyclerView);

           RetrievedData();
            //CreateData();
            //SetUpRecyClerView();
            return view;
        }
        private void SetUpRecyClerView()
        {
            myRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new Android.Support.V7.Widget.LinearLayoutManager(myRecyclerView.Context));
            adapter = new DriversAdapter(DriversList);
            myRecyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter);
        }
        public void CreateData()
        {
            DriversList = new List<Drivers>();
            DriversList.Add(new Drivers { Name = "Test", Location ="Test", BodyNum = "1056" });
            DriversList.Add(new Drivers { Name = "Test", Location ="Test",BodyNum = "1056", });

        }
        public void RetrievedData()
        {
            driversListener = new DriversListener();
            driversListener.Create();
            driversListener.DriversRetrieved += DriversListener_DriversRetrieved;
        }

        private void DriversListener_DriversRetrieved(object sender, DriversListener.DriversDataEventArgs e)
        {
             List<Drivers> SearchResult =
                (from drivers in DriversList
                 where drivers.BodyNum.Contains(searchText.Text.ToLower())
                 select drivers).ToList();
            DriversList = e.Drivers;
            SetUpRecyClerView();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add it in Driverlistfrag as searchText is there a simplier way to do that?

Comment: If you just need the text of searchText then why are you trying to add this view to the Driverlistfrag. While can get the text of searchText and pass this text string Driverlistfrag. Hope it may Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through the below link may be it will be helpful for you :

[How to pass data between Fragments in Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805102/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments-in-xamarin)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I modify your some code, please take a look:

In Rating.cs:

```
 private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText.Text))
        {
            Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.Make(view, "Please Enter A Value ", Snackbar.LengthShort);
            snackBar.Show();
        }
        else
        {

            FragmentTransaction transaction = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

            fragment = new DriversListFrag();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.PutString("message", searchText.Text.ToString());
            fragment.Arguments = bundle;

             transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.FramePage, fragment);
            transaction.Commit();

        }
    }
```

In DriversListFrag.cs:

```
 private void DriversListener_DriversRetrieved(object sender, DriversListener.DriversDataEventArgs e)
    {
         List<Drivers> SearchResult =
            (from drivers in DriversList
             where drivers.BodyNum.Contains(Arguments.GetString("message").ToLower())
             select drivers).ToList();
        DriversList = e.Drivers;
        SetUpRecyClerView();
    }
```