# How to pass value from activity to fragment using SupportFragmentManager in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, android-fragments

Im using the Android.Support.V4.App for fragments in my app, which means I need to use SupportFragmentManager. I couldn't find a way to put a value inside it so it can be passed to the fragment from the activity.
This is the code where I use it.

```
        var trans = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        trans.Add(Resource.Id.FramelayoutMain, new Fragment(), "MainFragment");
        trans.Commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

So after few hours of search I got to the point where its easier to do with the regular Using App, rather than with the v4.library.

Here is a dissent solution of how to do it in this way:

[How to pass data between Fragments in Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805102/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments-in-xamarin)